# Rails test setup causing warden's UncaughtThrowError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, devise, warden

I'm trying to adapt a pre-devise unit test to make sure that an unconfirmed user is not logged in and is redirected to the sign in page with the `devise.failure.unconfirmed` message. I keep running into a warden error. I know that I can get rid of the error by confirming the user, but that would defeat the purpose of the test. I believe this version of devise includes the relevant warden test setup in devise's integration_helpers.rb (`warden.test_mode!`, etc.).

The test code generates:
`UncaughtThrowError: uncaught throw :warden`

The equivalent actions in a localhost:3000 browser generate: 
`401` with a response body of `devise.failure.unconfirmed` which displays as expected.

**users_controller_test.rb**

```
require 'test_helper'
class UsersControllerTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
include Devise::Test::IntegrationHelpers
  test "should redirect index when not confirmed" do
    sign_in User.create!(name: 'Bob', email: 'bob@bob.com', password: 'password', password_confirmation: 'password)
    get users_path
  end
end
```

**test_helper.rb**

```
require File.expand_path('../../config/environment',__FILE__)
require 'rails/test_help'

class ActiveSupport::TestCase
  fixtures :all
end
```

**user.rb**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  devise :lockable, :confirmable, :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
...
end
```

versions: devise 4.4.1, rails 5.1.4, ruby 2.5.0

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting the same error. Since you have `:confirmable` in your user model, you should also have `confirmed_at` filled in as well, or confirm the user by some other means . I use fixtures, so it would look like this.

```
valid_user:
    email: user@example.com
    encrypted_password: foobar
    confirmed_at: 01/01/2018
```

I'm trying to catch that warden error with no luck though